# Pop out menu covered by jquery thumbnail slider

Tags: jquery, css, layer, overlap

I'm creating a site which needs to show a pop out menu and a thumbnail slider on the same page.

I'm using this technique for the pop out menu:
http://designshack.net/articles/pop-out-css-menu/

And this plugin for the slider:
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

They work fine individually, but when I add them to the same page, the slider overlaps the secondary menu items in the pop out menu. I've tried playing with the z-index but it didn't help. Is there anyway to have the secondary items to always display on top of everything?

Comment: PS: Here's what the page looks like now:
http://chroma-noise.com/joseph/cyrus/curtains/tc/2b.html
(The menu is on the left and the slider is the second last row at the bottom.)

Also note that the thumbnails open in an overlay using the prettyphoto plugin:
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In menu.css at line 41, set your z-index here:

```
#menu ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  z-index: 30;
}
```